# Add rows based on missing dates within a group

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to add rows to a data frame based on the minimum and maximum data **within** each group. Suppose this is my original data frame:

```
df = data.frame(Date = as.Date(c("2017-12-01", "2018-01-01", "2017-12-01", "2018-01-01", "2018-02-01","2017-12-01", "2018-02-01")),
            Group = c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3),
            Value = c(100, 200, 150, 125, 200, 150, 175))
```

Notice that Group 1 has 2 consecutive dates, group 2 has 3 consecutive dates, and group 3 is missing the date in the middle (2018-01-01). I'd like to be able to complete the data frame by adding rows for missing dates. But the thing is I only want to add additional dates based on dates that are missing between the minimum and maximum date within each group. So if I were to complete this data frame it would look like this:

```
df_complete = data.frame(Date = as.Date(c("2017-12-01", "2018-01-01", "2017-12-01", "2018-01-01", "2018-02-01","2017-12-01","2018-01-01", "2018-02-01")),
            Group = c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
            Value = c(100, 200, 150, 125, 200, 150,NA, 175))
```

Only one row was added because Group 3 was missing one date. There was no date added for Group 1 because it had all the dates between its minimum (2017-12-01) and maximum date (2018-01-01).

Answer (score 13):

You can use `tidyr::complete` with `dplyr` to find a solution. The `interval` between consecutive dates seems to be `month`. The approach will be as below:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% group_by(Group) %>%
  complete(Group, Date = seq.Date(min(Date), max(Date), by = "month"))

# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups: Group [3]
# Group Date       Value
# <dbl> <date>     <dbl>
#   1  1.00 2017-12-01   100
# 2  1.00 2018-01-01   200
# 3  2.00 2017-12-01   150
# 4  2.00 2018-01-01   125
# 5  2.00 2018-02-01   200
# 6  3.00 2017-12-01   150
# 7  3.00 2018-01-01    NA
# 8  3.00 2018-02-01   175
```

Data

```
df = data.frame(Date = as.Date(c("2017-12-01", "2018-01-01", "2017-12-01", "2018-01-01",
               "2018-02-01","2017-12-01", "2018-02-01")),
                Group = c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3),
                Value = c(100, 200, 150, 125, 200, 150, 175))
```

Comment: This will only work for numeric group columns that are typecast as numeric double values. If the "Group" column holds, e.g.,  character strings, it will be typecast as factors and the `complete()` operation results in a tibble with a row for every factor/time combination for each group.

Answer (score 2):

[@MKR's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49330319) of using `tidyr::complete` with `dplyr` is good, but will fail if the group column is not numeric. It will then be typecast as factors and the `complete()` operation will then result in a tibble with a row for every factor/time combination for each group.

`complete()` does not need the group variable as first argument, so the solution is

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% group_by(Group) %>%
  complete(Date = seq.Date(min(Date), max(Date), by = "month"))
```