# Complete missing dates with minimum and maximum date per group

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have the following dataframe df (`dput` below):

```
> df
  group      date1      date2 value
1     A 2023-01-04 2023-01-06     1
2     A 2023-01-06 2023-01-07     2
3     A 2023-01-08 2023-01-09     3
4     B 2023-01-05 2023-01-06     3
5     B 2023-01-06 2023-01-08     2
6     B 2023-01-08 2023-01-10     1
```

I would like to complete the missing dates between the minimum start date1 and maximum date2 per group. This means that for group A the interval of  `2023-01-07` to `2023-01-08` should be filled. The desired output should look like this:

```
  group      date1      date2 value
1     A 2023-01-04 2023-01-06     1
2     A 2023-01-06 2023-01-07     2
3     A 2023-01-07 2023-01-08    NA
4     A 2023-01-08 2023-01-09     3
5     B 2023-01-05 2023-01-06     3
5     B 2023-01-06 2023-01-08     2
6     B 2023-01-08 2023-01-10     1
```

So I was wondering if anyone knows how to complete these dates based on the minimum and maximum date per group?

---

data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  group = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 3L),
  date1 = c(
    "2023-01-04", "2023-01-06", "2023-01-08", "2023-01-05", "2023-01-06",
    "2023-01-08"
  ),
  date2 = c(
    "2023-01-06", "2023-01-07", "2023-01-09", "2023-01-06", "2023-01-08",
    "2023-01-10"
  ),
  value = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1)
)
```

Comment: Do the [answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49330037/add-rows-based-on-missing-dates-within-a-group) work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Effectively the same as my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76016090/3358272), though since we no longer need `start` and `end` dates, we need to shift (`lead`) one of them.

```r
out <- df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarize(newdate1 = date2, newdate2 = lead(date1)) %>%
  rename(date1 = newdate1, date2 = newdate2) %>%
  filter(date2 > date1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  bind_rows(df) %>%
  arrange(group, date1)
out
# # A tibble: 7 × 4
#   group date1      date2      value
#   <chr> <chr>      <chr>      <dbl>
# 1 A     2023-01-04 2023-01-06     1
# 2 A     2023-01-06 2023-01-07     2
# 3 A     2023-01-07 2023-01-08    NA
# 4 A     2023-01-08 2023-01-09     3
# 5 B     2023-01-05 2023-01-06     3
# 6 B     2023-01-06 2023-01-08     2
# 7 B     2023-01-08 2023-01-10     1
```